# The app disables security checks when creating new package contexts

Tags: android, flutter, appsweep

I am integrating Appsweep on my Flutter Application. After uploading the apk to AppSweep, it returns the following issue: The app disables security checks when creating new package contexts.
How can I solve this issue? I have also attached a full image of the issue (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vqe81.png).

Comment: Did you upload a `--release` app?

Comment: Yes, it is a --release app